# Restoring Subversion from Backup - Working Directories Way Newer

Tags: backup, svn, restore

Subversion is installed on an Amazon volume, which just died on us.  We have a snapshot from last night and are prepared to bring it up.  However, we've been working today and have committed several files throughout the day.

My concern is that the local working copies are going to reflect a much newer version than what is actually going to be on the server.  How should I go about getting the code on our computers into subversion with the least amount of disruption?

Do I need to checkout a new working copy from subversion once it's back up, do a diff between that and my current code and copy the changes over to the new working copy and commit it?

Or, can I keep the working directory that I have now and simply commit the files that are newer than what's on the backup on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be ok to get a diff of the changes since the crash and apply it, but if you do that I you'll need to make sure everyone checks out fresh working copies, or the local history will differ from the server. Applying the diffs again as they happened (revision by revision) might be enough. You should take care that people don't commit anything until you're finished reapplying the changes or it'll make your task harder.